# How to capture screen in selenium webdriver when using jasmine js?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Please your assistance in the following question:

**How to capture screen in selenium webdriver when using jasmine js?**

Not for errors, just to capture the website page during the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something described at [How can I get screenshots of failures?](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/fca9c5fc02c38c56cd9915485d051f4ba56692d4/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-screenshots-of-failures) FAQ page:

```
browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
  var stream = fs.createWriteStream("/tmp/screenshot.png");
  stream.write(new Buffer(png, 'base64'));
  stream.end();
});
```

[`takeScreenshot()` API reference](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.takeScreenshot).

Comment: Thanks! Is it for any capturing or only for failures?

Comment: @IdanE you can use it wherever you prefer.

Comment: Thanks again, But I've tried to use your code and I got an exception about it doesn't support "fs"..
:/

Comment: @IdanE sure, you need to require it: `var fs =  require('fs');`.